# Set Rajawali surface view layout parameters equal to JavaCameraView

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, surfaceview, rajawali

I am trying to put a 3d object over my JavaCameraView using Rajawali library. I have set the max frame size for JavaCameraView as follows:

javaCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(640,480);

I want my surface's layout parameters to match to those of javacameraview (width and height) but somehow I have not been able to achieve so. How do I do it ?

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    javaCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(640,480);


    final RajawaliSurfaceView surface = new RajawaliSurfaceView(this);
    surface.setFrameRate(60.0);
    surface.setRenderMode(IRajawaliSurface.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    surface.setTransparent(true);
    surface.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

    javaCameraView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(640, 480));
    // Add mSurface to your root view
    addContentView(surface, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(320, 240));


    renderer = new Renderer(this);
    surface.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);

    Log.d("NATIVE LOG", "Initialisation complete");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual text of the code instead of an image of it ? I'ts much easier to work with it for answers.

Comment: I have edited the question and put actual code there instead of image, Is it fine now ?

Comment: Seems fine now. I'm not able to answer tho, I'm just saying doing this will probably attracts more answers because it's easier to work with.